# Opengl/opencl deprecation: what can be the alternatives?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have lately decided to learn more about c++ visualization and parallel computing and came to know that mac has decided to deprecate opengl/opencl.

I am now about to make a decision about what to learn alternatively that can offer me flexibility across different platforms.

As it's suggested by mac developers, metal is the right replacement. However, part of my code needs to be run on other platforms and i cannot afford to learn several libraries/specifications to overcome this platform issue.

I have read enough online about this problem but still vague about what to do. So i would kindly ask a professional in this area that has a good perspective toward good options for the decade to come.

FYI, I plan to use these techniques for academic purposes so visualization performance doesnt really matter too much.

I also thought about VTK  but it may also experience some change as it's based on opengl. For parallelization, I need to use both cpu and gpu programming.

Answer (score 1):

Although the documentation has disappeared, it's still possible to develop and run code that does OpenGL/OpenCL. In fact, I'm writing OpenGL on a Mac as we speak. If performance isn't an issue, run a Linux variant in a VM. Performance in Parallels tracks pretty closely to running on the host OS.

Comment: Thanks bill. My concern is, would it be a good idea to start investing time in learning opengl/cl now considering the fact that it's already been deprecated in mac and may also experience the same fate in other platforms? I don't think this is the right choice. So the question would be, is there any other cross-platform options? both for visualization and parallelization

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL/OpenCL are likely to be replaced by SYCL, but in the distant future. Apple is aggressive with Metal. Windows has DirectX. Linux distributions tend to never really obsolete stuff. Consider X11.

What matters is which platforms you need to develop for. If Apple, focus on Metal. I don’t think the concepts you’ll learn with OpenCL/GL will hurt regardless.